# Не отображается текст виджета QLineEdit с задержкой time.sleep

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Пользователь вводит букву в поле виджета **QLineEdit**, затем через секунду поле должно очиститься. Пауза работает, но текст не появляется. Как это сделать можно?

```
import sys, time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.qle = QLineEdit()
        self.qle.textEdited.connect(self.method)

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.qle)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

    def method(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.qle.clear()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.resize(300, 70)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: общее правило для большинства GUI библиотек: не используйте блокирующие вызовы (такие как time.sleep) в обработчиках событий. Чтобы выполнить с задержкой какое-то действие, как правило есть соответствующее API. Вот примеры кода для нескольких библиотек https://stackoverflow.com/a/14040516/4279

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы используете петлю обработки событий `QApplication`, не стоит пользоваться питоновским\системным `sleep`. В `Qt` есть для этого `QTimer`.
В данном случае можно использовать статический метод `singleShot`. Он принимает параметры задержки в *мс* и слот-обработчик.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        qle = QLineEdit()
        qle.textEdited.connect(lambda: QTimer.singleShot(2000, qle.clear))

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(qle)
        self.setLayout(vbox)   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.resize(300, 70)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

В вашем же случае получалось, что `time.sleep` блокировал поток выполнения (поэтому текст не появлялся), через 2 секунды управление возвращалось приложению, происходила очистка текстового поля виджета, перерисовка окна.

Answer (score 1):

Для Qt можно использовать его "sleep" – используя `QEventLoop`. А таймер тут нужен только для того, чтобы можно было выйти из цикла событий:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QEventLoop


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.qle = QLineEdit()
        self.qle.textEdited.connect(self.method)

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.qle)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

    def method(self):
        loop = QEventLoop()
        QTimer.singleShot(2000, loop.quit)
        loop.exec()

        self.qle.clear()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.resize(300, 70)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Есть одна интересная реализация отложенного вызова для `QLineEdit`, пока выполняется ввод.

Например, вводится куча текста и нужно после окончания ввода (например, через 2 секунды) сделать сохранение или проверку.

Тогда на помощь приходит таймер с одиночным использованием. Т.е. каждый сигнал `textEdited` или запускает таймер, или перезапускает его.

А при реализации выше каждый сигнал `textEdited` создает новый запуск метода, таким образом произойдет куча ненужных вызовов:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.qle = QLineEdit()

        self.time = QTimer()
        self.time.setSingleShot(True)
        self.time.setInterval(2000)
        self.time.timeout.connect(self.qle.clear)

        self.qle.textEdited.connect(self.time.start)

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.qle)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.resize(300, 70)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```